# Volume of sub-manifold of $\mathbf R^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, embeddings, metric-embeddings

Let $M$ be an $n-m$ dimensional sub-manifold of $\mathbf R^n$ defined by the following set of polynomial equations:
\begin{equation}
P_1(\vec x)=0, \\
\vdots \\
P_m(\vec x)=0,
\end{equation}
(where $\vec x$ are coordinates in $\mathbf R^n$).
How can the volume of $M$ be expressed in terms of the data contained in the polynomials $P_1,\dotsc,P_m$?

Comment: What do you mean by "volume"? The Lebesgue measure will be zero if $m \geq 1$. (But there is probably still a sensible way to define lower-dimensional volume...)

Comment: @SamHopkins Volume as in $\int_M \sqrt{\det g}$ where $g$ is the induced metric.

Comment: Probably the simplest expression would be the Cauchy-Crofton theorem.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Could you tell us what sort of expression you would accept as an answer when $m=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: @RobertBryant Simply the volume expressed as a function of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: @dennis:  Good luck with that.  The length of the ellipse $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ is a non-elementary function of $a$ and $b$, expressed in terms of an elliptic integral.   Getting an explicit formula for the length of, say, a bounded quartic curve in terms of the coefficients of the quartic polynomial defining it is almost certainly hopeless.